# git filter for clang-format with IncludeIsMainRegex

Tags: c++, git, clang-format

I want to run clang-format on every check in on any edited `.cpp` and `.h` file in a git repository and make sure that the "main include file" is on top.

There is [a filter option](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code) for this in `.gitattributes`:

```
*.cpp filter=clang-format-cpp
*.h filter=clang-format-cpp
```

for which the relevant filter can be locally configured with

```
git config --global filter.clang-format-cpp.clean 'clang-format -assume-filename=test.cpp'
```

For clang-format, [there is an option `IncludeIsMainRegex`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) which will always put the "main include file" on top. E.g. with `IncludeIsMainRegex: '(test_?)?$'` for a file `a.cpp` or `test_a.cpp`, the header `a.h` will be the main include and hence put on top.

However, when the file is formatted through the git filter/clang-format, this main include is not put on top.

#### Given

**.clang-format**:

```
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(test_?)?$'
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
```

**z.cpp**:

```
#include "z.h"
#include "other.h"
#include <includes.h>
#include <here.h>
```

#### Expected

**z.cpp**:

```
#include "z.h"

#include "other.h"

#include <here.h>
#include <includes.h>
```

#### Result

**z.cpp**:

```
#include "other.h"
#include "z.h"

#include <here.h>
#include <includes.h>
```

The reason is very likely that the file is sent through clang-format with stdin/stdout and therefore clang-format does not know the filename (or rather assumes it's test.cpp) and hence cannot determine the main include.

One alternative approach would be to setup a pre-commit hook and let it correct the file in place upon commit. But having them corrected upon staging is much more streamlined than upon committing.

How can clang-format be integrated in a git workflow to automatically put the main include file on top?

For now I just disabled `IncludeIsMainRegex: false` and this works stable regardless if `clang-format` is called on the file or via git filter.

Answer (score 1):

it is because you don't put Priority, if you set like this :

```
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IncludeCategories:
    - Regex: '^".*"'
      Priority: 1
```

it's work because #include "z.h" is by default 0 priority and if you don't put priority to your regex it take 0 too